# Cannot run Swift under Ubuntu after closing the terminal

Tags: linux, swift, terminal

I am trying to run the Swift compiler under Ubuntu. I followed this tutorial: https://itsfoss.com/use-swift-linux/ and everything seemed to work fine. I was able to run swift under Ubuntu.

However, when I closed the terminal, I was not able to run Swift anymore. The program was not found until I installed it again. I could not find any answers to this question as there aren't many people running Swift under Ubuntu.

Comment: How are you sure that it's uninstalled?

Comment: It hasn't been uninstalled. Ubuntu needs the `PATH` variable to be set correctly in order to find programs. Check my answer.

Comment: you are right!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not uninstalled, you just don't have the environment variables set up anymore, so Bash can't find the path to Swift. You can change that by `export`ing the appropriate environment variables in your `.bashrc` file.

When you followed the tutorial, you ran the following command:

```
export PATH=path_to_swift_usr_bin:$PATH
```

This command adds the path to the `swift` binary to your `PATH` environment variable. The `PATH` variable holds a list of places where Ubuntu will look for programs to run from the command-line. So if the Swift executable is not in one of the places listed in the `PATH`, your terminal will never find it.

There is a file in your home folder (the folder `~`, which is an abbreviation for `/home/username`, where `username` is your username) named `.bashrc`, which runs whenever you open a new terminal window. If you need an environment variable to be available whenever you open the terminal, you should add the `export` line for that variable to your `.bashrc`.

In this case, your `.basrhc` should contain the same line above.

The important thing to remember is that your environment variables are *not* preserved between command-line sessions, so if you want to have an environment variable available every time you use the command-line, it needs to be defined in your `.bashrc`.